# get ip and send it by email

Tags: php, button, ip, submit

I have this simple code:

```
<?php 
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") ; 
Echo "". $ip;
?>
```

Id like to have an ip number appears in the field form in order to directly send it to an email. People who enter that *file.php* see their ip in the field and are able to push the button "SEND" in order to send it to me. 
Thanks.

Comment: So what happens if I write an automated script to click the button `2^36` times ?? You shoudn't do that actually.. Make a captcha or track the IP with some session and then let the user click the button.

Comment: hmmm i guess that will be a lot fun.. :D :D please do it and send the link over :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
mail ('me@gmail.com', 'ip of visitor', $ip);
?>
```

Get visitor real Ip

```
<?PHP

function getUserIP(){
    $clientIp  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forwardIp = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remoteIp  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($clientIp, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $clientIp;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forwardIp, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forwardIp;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remoteIp;
    }

    return $ip;
}


    $user_ip = getUserIP();

    echo $user_ip; // Output IP address [127.0.0.1] .i run this script on my local host


?>
```

Comment: what happens if it is a proxy? is there a way to get real ip?

Answer (score 1):

The Following code is complete and works, just replace the example email usernames and passwords and smtp server, and save all the below code in a .php file.

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
$client_ip = get_client_ip();
$from = "Sender <EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.com>";
$to = "Receiver <EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.com>";
$subject = "Subject EXAMPLE \r\n\r\n";
$body = "Your client's ip is: " .$client_ip;

$host = "smtp.EXAMPLE.com";
$port = "25";
$username = "EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE";
$password = "PasswordEXAMPLE";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'port' => $port,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
   $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
return $ipaddress;
} 
// if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
//  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
//} else {
//  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
// }

//If you want to activate STEALTH MODE, the following code will redirect the 
//user to another URL,
header("Location: http://www.google.com");

?>
```